# Simple actor/task abstraction

Tags: c++, beginner

I'm interested in creating a simple game but what I realized was that half-way through development I get lost in the details with the design. In particular, I find dependency injection, unit testing/mocking and proper abstractions like interfaces to be overwhelming. I figured if I wanted to avoid having problems, I should practice those concepts in a toy project. Here's the code:

**task.hpp**

```
#ifndef TASK_HPP
#define TASK_HPP

#include <functional>

class itask {
public:
    virtual ~itask() = default;
    virtual void operator()() const = 0;
    virtual void bind(std::function<void()> f) = 0;
};

class task : public itask {
    std::function<void()> action_;
public:
    task() { }

    void bind(std::function<void()> f) override {
        action_ = f;
    }

    void operator()() const override {
        action_();
    }
};

#endif
```

**actor.hpp**

```
#ifndef ACTOR_HPP
#define ACTOR_HPP

#include <memory>
#include <task.hpp>
#include <vector>

class iactor {
public:
    virtual ~iactor() = default;
    virtual void add_task(std::shared_ptr<itask>) = 0;
    virtual void do_task() = 0;
};

class actor : public iactor {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<itask>> tasks_;
public:
    actor() { }

    void add_task(std::shared_ptr<itask> t) override {
        tasks_.emplace_back(t);
    }

    void do_task() override {
        (*tasks_.back().get())();
        tasks_.pop_back();
    }
};

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <actor.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <sstream>
#include <functional>
#include <task.hpp>
#include <vector>

struct bark : public itask {
public:
    bark() { }

    void bind(std::function<void()> f) override {
        assert("Cannot bind to this task.");
    }

    void operator()() const override {
        std::cout << "Woof, woof!\n";
    }
};

struct dog : public iactor {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<itask>> tasks_;
public:
    dog() { }

    void add_task(std::shared_ptr<itask> t) override {
        auto try_cast = dynamic_cast<bark*>(t.get());
        if (!try_cast) {
            assert("Pupper can't do what you asked.");
        } else {
            tasks_.emplace_back(t);
        }
    }

    void do_task() override {
        (*tasks_.back().get())();
        tasks_.pop_back();
    }
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<iactor> good_boy = std::make_unique<dog>();
    std::unique_ptr<itask> t = std::make_unique<bark>();

    good_boy->add_task(std::move(t));

    good_boy->do_task();
}
```

**test-actor.cpp**

```
#include "catch.hpp"
#include "fakeit.hpp"
#include <actor.hpp>
#include <memory>

TEST_CASE("wow he really can act!", "[actor]") {
    using namespace fakeit;

    Mock<iactor> actor_mock;

    auto arg = std::make_shared<task>();
    arg->bind([] () {
        std::cout << "Welcome to the test.\n";
    });

    When(Method(actor_mock, add_task).Using(arg)).AlwaysReturn();
    When(Method(actor_mock, do_task)).AlwaysReturn();

    auto &do_stuff = actor_mock.get();
    do_stuff.add_task(arg);
    do_stuff.do_task();

    Verify(Method(actor_mock, add_task).Using(arg));
    Verify(Method(actor_mock, do_task));
}
```

**test-task.cpp**

```
#include "catch.hpp"
#include "fakeit.hpp"
#include <task.hpp>
#include <memory>

TEST_CASE("reporting for duty, sir", "[task]") {
    using namespace fakeit;

    Mock<itask> task_mock;

    auto arg = [] () {
        std::cout << "Welcome to the test.\n";
    };

    When(Method(task_mock, bind)).AlwaysReturn();
    When(Method(task_mock, operator())).AlwaysReturn();

    auto &do_stuff = task_mock.get();
    do_stuff.bind(arg);
    do_stuff();

    Verify(Method(task_mock, bind));
    Verify(Method(task_mock, operator()));
}
```

Ultimately I'd like to have a lot of different objects with injectable dependencies like a world class that can have a lot of actors. And actors can either be generic (just takes some tasks and executes them) or have specialized behavior like the `dog` class (only accepts certain types of tasks). My questions are:

- Is my approach scalable? Does it make sense?
- Am I testing the interface correctly? Do I need to change/remove the `bind` function?
- Am I using smart pointers correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Does your code make sense? Not really.

`bark` violates the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). And very ineptly, using `assert()`, which will disappear in a release-build compile with `-DNDEBUG`.

Either remove `bind` from `itask` and create a subclass accepting a callable, or just use `std::function` directly and accept the possible extra-allocation.